# Is there a way to completely insert the contents of one module into another?

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I need a code to place inside `__using__`, which would quote all the module at once, instead of manually copying it there.

Or maybe there is a simplier way?

The goal is to make an instance of the module with the different name. The instance should be able to start under supervision and should have an ability to be extended with other functions.

The Instance should be generated at compile-time.

The draft looks like:

```
defmacro __using__(_) do
   quote do
      __MODULE__
   end
end
```

It obviously does not work, and it should not, but the solution seems to be somewhere out there.

```
defmodule Instance do
   use Model
end
```

And it would inject entire Model's contents into the Instance.

Comment: What would be wrong with `AliasModule = BareModule`?

Comment: I need an Instance module, capable of starting under supervision, etc.

Moreover, it would be great to preserve a capabitiy of adding functions after injecting the Model.

Comment: Then declare the helper module `BaseFunctionality` that exports `__using__/1` and `use BaseFunctionality` in _both_ modules. After compilation, the AST is unavailable, so what you propose is impossible to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking just about that way, but I wondered if there might be a more elegant way to do what I need.

Comment: It is extremely hard to tell what _exactly_ you need from the description above. One might e.g. dynamically create modules with [`Module.create/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Module.html#create/3) and when I need several instances of the same code in runtime I usually use it.

Comment: FWIW, my [`Envío`](https://github.com/am-kantox/envio) package produces same instances almost exactly as you want, feel free to use it as an inspiration. E.g. [this module](https://github.com/am-kantox/envio/blob/master/lib/envio/subscriber.ex) plays as a scaffold for the package users.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to flaws in the question, I've updated it. And big thanks for clarifications!